# Jquery ajax change style sheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am just looking on these two pages:

1. http://www.tipue.com/search/demos/static/
2. http://www.google.com

What happens is the style of the page changes, even though the page is only updated via AJAX. So my question is, what is the most compliant and efficient way of changing the look of the page, after an AJAX request. Is it about having two stylesheets which are switched, or overwriting the contents of a single stylesheet using JavaScript?

Comment: Mostly it's like loading all stylesheets in start only. And after ajax request browser adapts stylesheet of elements if matches in stylesheet already loaded in start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most **compliant** way would be to change the styling indirectly while seperate styling from functionality. this is accomplished through adding css rules for each desired state and then switch around classes with your javascript logic (after an ajax call):

```
$('.js-dynamic-entity').addClass('huge');
```

Alot of the times we cannot do that for example when you have to set a very specific value in a big range let us say the height of an element between 50 and 500 pixels. In this case you would use the jquery css method, which is also very common:

```
$('.js-dynamic-entity').css({height: 457});
```

If you want to do a **ton** of styling work after an ajax call, then you can as well consider to load in a styling sheet per jquery like this:

```
$('<style />').appendTo('body').html(dynamicallyLoadedSheet);
```

Personally the latter version does not make too much sense to me except we're talking about huge differences in styling which are only used in special cases.

Answer (score 1):

All you do is have another stylesheet and change the value in the link tag "href" of the page. That should do the job. For example, it's just like changing the src of a image. You can use jquery to easily accomplish that.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript DOM is the easiest solution. Instead of updating CSS stylesheets, you can easily make user-mode changes and later (eventually) save these changes with AJAX. [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_dynamic_styling_information?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FDOM%2FUsing_dynamic_styling_information) article is a good start point for JS DOM.